# React extract value from list-keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, hashmap

```
 getEmployeeCredits(id) {
        if (this.state.company_roles) {
            return this.state.company_roles.map(function (cr, i) {
                if (cr.id  === id) {
                    return cr.assigned_credits
                }
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
```

I want to return the assigned credits of the company role whose value matches over here. But the value which is returned is: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, "10000.0"]`.

In this the undefined value is because of company roles for which the values didn't match. I can delete all the `undefined` values and then just use the value `10000.0` but is there a more elegant way to do this?

EDIT: THE `if (cr.id === id)` condition will always be true for only a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look-up an array for a single value, use `Array.prototype.find`.

Adjusted to your example:

`const foundCompanyRoleItem = this.state.company_roles.find(crItem => crItem.id === id);
 return foundCompanyRoleItem.assigned_credits;`

This will always return a matching value instead of an array as in the case of `.filter`.

P.S.: I suggest to use ES6 syntax for your project as well. In the above example, you can see the benefit as my example uses an arrow function introduced in ES6. It makes expressions cleaner and more reasonable.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to achieve what I want. Thanks

Comment: And I'll look into using ES6 syntax for my project. It does look way cleaner

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just trying...

```
return this.state.company_roles.filter(function (cr, i) {
                if (cr.id  === id) {
                    if(cr.assigned_credits!=undefined)
                       return cr.assigned_credits;
                    else 
                       return false;
                }
```

When you get the array, you can remove the undefined values using `Array.prototype.filter`

Eg:

```
var data = [42, 21, undefined, 50, 40, undefined, 9];

data = data.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: That is true I can remove the undefined values from the returned `cr.assigned_credits`. I was wondering if there's a way to only return the value of `assigned_credits` when the if condition is true and then it will only return a single value instead of an array

Comment: Sure! Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use directly `filter` on company_roles ?

```
getEmployeeCredits(id) {
  if (this.state.company_roles) {
    return this.state.company_roles.filter(cr => cr.id  === id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the if statement which is true for only one value , the rest are returning undefined implicitly.

```
getEmployeeCredits(id) {
            if (this.state.company_roles) {
                return this.state.company_roles.map(function (cr, i) {
                    if (cr.id  === id) {
                        return cr.assigned_credits
                    }
                    else 
                       return undefined;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        }
```

so to solve it you need to

```
return this.state.company_roles.filter((role) => role.id ===id ).assigned_credits;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` transforms all values in one array to another array and both arrays will always have same length. If you want to extract single object from array as mentioned above `Array.filter` or `Array.find` will be better for this purpose. Keep in mind that `Array.find` is part of ES6 standard which means it may not be supported in some browsers.